# win32 redrawing after resizing

Tags: c++, winapi

I have next problems

I have base class "Shape", it cointains virtual function `draw(HWND)`, I have child class "Line" which contains same function `draw(hwnd)`.

When I draw line in `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, it is all ok, but when I minimize or change window size, my line disappear

What I need to do?

I have vector with pointer to base class
vector ff;
Shape *f;

```
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
{

    IsDrawing = TRUE;

    StartX = LOWORD(lParam);
    StartY = HIWORD(lParam);
    EndX = LOWORD(lParam);
    EndY = HIWORD(lParam);

    switch(iShape)
    {
    case LINE:
            f=new Line();
        break;
    case  RECTANGLE:
        f=new MyRectangle();
        break;
    }

    f->SetBrushWidth(5);
    f->SetColor(RGB(255,0,0));
    f->SetStartCoord(StartX,StartY);
    f->SetEndCoord(EndX,EndY);
    f->SetMode(1);
    f->draw(hWnd);
    break;
}

case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
if( IsDrawing == TRUE )
{
    f->SetEndCoord(EndX,EndY);
    f->SetMode(2);
    f->draw(hWnd);
    EndX = LOWORD(lParam);
    EndY = HIWORD(lParam);
    f->SetEndCoord(EndX,EndY);
    f->SetMode(2);
    f->draw(hWnd);
}

break;

case WM_LBUTTONUP:


EndX = LOWORD(lParam);
EndY = HIWORD(lParam);

f->SetEndCoord(EndX,EndY);
f->SetMode(3);
f->draw(hWnd);
ff.push_back(f);

IsDrawing = FALSE;

break;
```

It is drawing ok, but when change windows size

Answer (score 8):

You are drawing in the wrong place. Drawing on a window should be done in response to receiving a `WM_PAINT` message. Windows can be redrawn at any time and your program must be able to completely redraw itself.

You need to move all your drawing code into the handling code for `WM_PAINT`. In the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` handler you need to make a note of where the line must be drawn, and then call `InvalidateRect`. This will schedule a paint cycle and the window can be repainted when that paint cycle occurs.

This is pretty much Win32 101 and I suggest that, if you have not already done so, you get hold of a copy of Petzold's classic tome, [Programming Windows](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/).